# c++ subclass as parameter of method

Tags: c++, class, parameters, subclass

I want to write two classes, in superclass i need method witch as a parameter have a subclass like in this sample code:

```
class class1
{
    int a;
    void print(class2 k)
    {
        cout<<k.b*a;
    }  
};

class class2 :public class1
{
    public:
    int b;
};
```

Unfortunately this isn't right ;-) and i can't figure it out, could anybody help?

Comment: Do you really want to pass this thing by *value*?

Comment: @JohnDibling I think an even better question is "do you really want to pass a derived class to a base class?"

Comment: That is a better question, but you already asked it in your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a forward declaration and move the implementation outside the `class`:

```
class class2;
class class1
{
    int a;
    void print(class2 k);
};

class class2 :public class1
{
    public:
    int b;
};
```

You can't keep the method inline because you need a full type for `class2` which can't be available at that point.

**But the main issue here is the design**, which is wrong. Why would a base class need to know and more-so call methods from a derived class?

Comment: My answer was wrong. Didn't know you can pass by value after forward declaration. Cool!

Comment: @Andrew I actually had my doubts first time.

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried something like that but get confused and keep making mistakes ;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
class class2;

class class1
{
    int a;
    inline void print(class2 &k); //pass by reference, but implemented after class2 is completely known to the compiler.
};

class class2 :public class1
{
    public:
    int b;
};

void class1::print(class2 &k)
{
    cout<<k.b*a;
}
```

Comment: Why pass by reference? I mean you can, but you don't have to.

Comment: Because the compiler has to know at least size of the parameter wqhen it sees the prototype, and for `class2` it cannot know it. But it can for reference `class2&` or pointer `class2*`.

Comment: That's wrong, you *can* pass by value with only a forward declaration. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem is not to implement `print()` within the base class but to oblige any inheriting class to implement it using a *pure virtual function.* At the moment, you'd probbaly call your code using:

```
class2 c2;
c2.b = 20; // for example
class1 c1;
c1.print( c2 );
```

but maybe a better way to implement this would be as follows:

```
class class1
{
protected:
    int a;

public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class class2 : public class1
{
public:
    int b;
    void print() const;
};

void class2::print() const
{
    cout << b * a;
}
```

So now `class2` is obliged to implement the print function which is correct in a sense **because `class2` should know about `class1` but not vice-versa.** Now you can do this:

```
class2 c2;
c2.b = 20; // for example
c2.print()
```

Of course, this may not help you with what you want to do but I would think it's generally a better way of approaching the problem you describe.